# CSS of previous list of elements gets applied to new list of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have 6 `<div>` which act as different applications. Each `<div>` contains a menu and each menu contains child menus which is an unordered list.
Each child menu contains `<img>` and `<p>` tag.

I have created a back button as I will be traversing between each of these `<div>`, menu and child menus. All these elements will be having an Id.

I have created an array to store history of all the list of elements, which I will be visiting using

```
var pageHistory = { "History": [] };
```

On click of each `<div>`, menu and child menu, I am adding them to `pageHistory` array using `pageHistory.History.push(menu);`

This is working fine. 
But when I click on back button and go from one `<div>` to another `<div>`, then the CSS of the child menu of earlier selected `<div>` gets applied to the child menu of newly selected `<div>`.

Also, the selected menu is not highlighted when I click on back button.

I want to change the CSS of each element as it is and highlight the selected menu and child menu on click of back button.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provided the code and sample markup as well as just describing the code and markup.

Answer (score 0):

Modern web applications often load data or changes in the document object model (DOM) via AJAX without leaving the original page, to create a desktop-like experience. To do that we can take advantage of the URL hash value and the benefits it give us, including less bandwidth used by the client, faster response time and eventually a more interactive application feeling. By inserting a hash character into the URL we can pick up the string following it and use it as a value in AJAX requests. We can also create a listener event to check for a hash being added to a URL and use it to activate a custom JavaScript.

**So for that please use hash change and activate your custom css using js**